# EC2 Dashboard says instnce running but DevOps says ec2 instance is stopping/restarting

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am facing a really weird issue with AWS. I have four ec2 instances which are in running state on the ec2 dashboard. However, when I view them under dev ops it says they are stopping or restarting state. I can still ssh into them but the instance is not available on the client end.

I had tried to deploy some code (around 12 hours ago), the deployment failed due to low disk space (probably because of log file size). However, the instance stopped just now, not when the deployment failed.

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: OpsWorks took instances out of their mapped Elastic Load Balancers due to an AWS outage just now. Fix by manually managing the ELB, if that works for you (it doesn't for me).

Long version: OpsWorks sees the instances as unhealthy (like, system-wide, all instances are unhealthy), so it's trying to fix the situation. It can't, because some backend service died. But it tries. So, it tries to stop/terminate and start instances, after removing them from their load balancers. This means you're down, and you can't do anything about it except try to put already running instances into your ELB. If you can. Good luck.